# C# How do I add a console app to a MonoGame project

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'd like to know how I can add a console application to an existing MonoGame project so that when I need to debug I can write to console

Thanks

Comment: Why not using `System.Diagnostics.Trace` or `System.Diagnostics.Debug` ?

Comment: Not sure what that is sorry. I know enough C# to do things but I'm still relatively new. Could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there a to options for this:

### 1) Solve this by separating Render / Game Logic

Simply split your Game Logic apart from your building MonoGame project and reference them separately. For better understanding i put an example picture below.

[image: Poorly drawn example picture]

---

### 2) Using `.net` Diagnostics in your Code

If you use the standard `Debug.WriteLine` or `Trace.WriteLine`, then output goes to the default trace listener which can be viewed in the **Visual Studio output window**. Outside of Visual Studio, you can use programs such as DebugView (SysInternals) or LogFusion (Binary Fortress) to display the output. DebugView even has a feature for viewing debug output from a remote machine.

There are other trace listeners that can send output to a file, or to the Windows event log, or you can write your own trace listeners fairly easily.